# How to avoid loops - shifting and summing instead?

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements

I am trying to put a threshold /cut-off for one of my activities,  Awaken, because it shouldn't last for more than 0.048 seconds according to the software, but some glitches occur where it lasts for 30 seconds. Unless the subject is in an awakened state beyond the mortal realm, I'd like to cut off at 0.048 seconds and whatever excess duration remains, to sum it to the next activity's duration.

The following code DOES work, however I have over 2 million rows of data and the loop is excessively slow. I tried another method (below this code)  but it doesn't add the difference to the next activity.

Here is the data:

```
    Duration Activity
2157    2.02120  Twitch
2158    2.21839  Sleep
2159    0.64086  Awaken
2160    0.44367  Dig
```

And this is my code

```
threshold = 0

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Activity'] == 'Awaken':
        if row['Duration'] > 0.048:
            threshold = row['Duration'] - 0.048

            df.at[i, 'Duration'] = 0.048
    else:
        if threshold > 0:
            df.at[i, 'Duration'] += threshold
            threshold = 0
```

Now, this works. It correctly adds the excess duration of Awaken to the next one, in this case, "dig".

However, I'm trying to avoid using a loop as it is VERY slow, and I did this, but this doesn't add it correctly. I'm not sure what im doing wrong. It gives a Nan value for the PREVIOUS activity duration.

```
awaken_cond = df1['Activity'] == 'Awaken'
excess_duration = df1.loc[awaken_cond, 'Duration'] - 0.048
df1.loc[awaken_cond, 'Duration'] = 0.048
df1.loc[awaken_mask.shift(-1).fillna(False), 'Duration'] += excess_duration.shift(-1)
```

This gives me this output:

```
      Duration     Activity
2157    2.02120    Twitch
2158    Nan        Sleep
2159    0.048      Awaken
2160    0.44367     Dig
```

Not sure how to move forward! Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: If the data comes from an RDBMS, a faster alternative is running a query there. Otherwise, use a loop but for each iteration check if the running time has exceeded the limit and break out if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
timediff = df.Duration + (df.Duration.shift(1) - 0.048)
adjtime = np.where(df.Activity.shift(1) == 'Awaken', timediff, df.Duration)
finaltime = np.where(df.Activity == 'Awaken', 0.048, adjtime)

# finaltime: array([2.0212 , 2.21839, 0.048  , 1.03653])
```

Unfortunately, this fails if you have consecutive 'Awaken' in your dataframe or the last entry is 'Awaken.' Do these edge cases exist in your dataframe?